# How do I add JTextField text to a String[] array

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing

I need to add the text typed into a `JTextField` into a `String[] storing` after I click a `JButton`. I am not allowed to use an `ArrayList` so please do not recommend that. For example, I will have a `JTextField`, I will write a statement such as, "Code Test" and then click a `JButton`, after that `JButton` click, the "Code Test" should be added to a `String[] storing`. I need to keep adding to the `String[] storing` for every new text that is followed by a `JButton` click.

```
    if(event.getSource() == buttonj) {
storing[jtextf.getText()];

}
```

Comment: Can you use any other kind of `Collection`?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do in this case is have some integer variable outside the button's event listener, but still inside the same class, representing the number of strings currently in `storing`. And then use this count to index the array when adding a new element, and increment the count every time you add a new string like so,

```
private static int count = 0;

if(event.getSource() == buttonj) {
    if(count < storing.length) {
        storing[count] = jtextf.getText();
        count++;
    }
}
```

Like user Kevin Anderson mentioned, be wary of when your array becomes full, aka when `count == storing.length`. At this point, you can either not add the element because the array is considered "full" or resize the array to fit in the new element. However I'll leave that part up to you.

Comment: Don't forget to consider what should happen when `storing` is full (i.e., when `count == storing.length`).

Comment: @KevinAnderson Good point, just edited my answer to include that.